# Can we do Yield curves using Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, adobe, yield, curves

I want to create Yield curves using adobe flex. pls, any one have an Idea how to create yield curves in a chart using flex...

Answer (score 1):

if you have data you should use something like this:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/charting/

if you just want to draw curve use this:

http://www.axelscript.com/2010/08/02/flex-4-implementing-bezier-curve-part-2/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS5B6A8436-0FF5-4029-8524-C7C1106C483D.html